# Retain dropdown user selected option after ng-change event is triggered

Tags: angularjs

How can I retain a drop down list box value selected by the user after the ng-change event has been triggered?

```
  <select class="form-control" id="myId" placeholder=""  ng-model="myModel" ng-required="true" ng-options="myoption as myOptionModel for myOption in myOptions" ng-required="true" ng-change="callOnChange()"/>
```

The user selected value should be shown as selected in the drop down list box. Currently, after a drop down value is selected it goes to the initial state (as if nothing has been selected), although, I can access the selected value in the callOnChange() function.

For example: If the list has three values "Apple", "Mango", "Orange" and the user selects "Mango", then "Mango" should remain selected after the ng-change event is triggered. Currently, when I select a value, I see a blank value followed by "Apple", "Mango" & "Orange".

Comment: so you are saying you want to retain the first value after user selecting any other value..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not use well the select, try this:

html:

```
<select placeholder=""  ng-model="myModel" ng-required="true" ng-change="callOnChange()">
   <option ng-repeat="myoption in mail_notifications" value="{{myoption.key}}">{{myoption.value}}</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.callOnChange=function() {
    alert("hello");

  }
    $scope.mail_notifications = [
        {
            "key": "1",
            "value": "example1"
        },
        {
                "key": "2",
            "value": "example2"
        },
        {
            "key": "3",
            "value": "example3"
        }
    ];
    $scope.myModel = '';
```

and the example: https://jsfiddle.net/javierif/nbofm5ah/